# Flash screen Android

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to create an effect which looks like the flash you seen when you take a screenshoot of the device.

My question, is there any way to do this?  and if so can i change the colour of that little flash?

Comment: I think you mean splash screen?

Comment: maybe i'm mistaken, but a splash screen is a "view" witch is shown at the start of the app. I'm wrong?

Comment: [that](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/systemui/screenshot/GlobalScreenshot.java#GlobalScreenshot.createScreenshotDropInAnimation%28%29) is what the screenshot app does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout as your root view.

Then, you'll have two layers, your content on the bottom, and a view on the top.

When the user triggers the event, you'll set the color of the view programatically to acheive the flash effect.